# How to install wacm graphical tablet to Linux Mint?

Tags: tablet

I tried to follow this [webpage](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source).

I have become stuck on this:
[image]

EDIT after advice:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `apt` command (on debian based distributions) rather than `yum`:

```
sudo apt install wacom
```

To build the package you should use :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot

sudo apt install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Building steps (instructions from : [Installing input wacom from source)](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source):

```
wget https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/releases/download/input-wacom-0.46.0/input-wacom-0.46.0.tar.bz2
tar xvf input-wacom-0.46.0.tar.bz2
cd input-wacom-0.46.0/
#./autogen.sh
if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe -v wacom
sudo modprobe -v wacom_w8001
```

Comment: @ElenaGreg Just run `xsetwacom --list devices` to get information about your device then use `xsetwacom --set` to configure your stylus.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't need to install `xserver-xorg-input-wacom`

Comment: The settings is not necessary, isn't it?

Comment: How to open the driver, please?

Comment: @ElenaGreg It is used to change settings, The driver is already loaded by `modprobe command`. Try rebooting.

Comment: `modprobe: FATAL: Module command not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-64-generic`

Comment: I have run it and the error stay the same.

Comment: @ElenaGreg run `sudo depmod` then`sudo modprobe -v wacom`

Comment: Thank you, I have run it. Is it replacement of `modprobe command`. What should be the result? The program graphical tablet should start to work, or there should be a program wacom?

Comment: @ElenaGreg After executing `modprobe -v module`  it will display something like `...ko` . This mean that the kernel module is loaded correctly.

Comment: I have still FATAL error for this command

Comment: @ElenaGreg Disable secure boot from your Bios settings. Then try  the `modprobe` command.

Comment: Without any parameters? It gives `modprobe: ERROR: missing parameters.`

Comment: It was OK, it did not show anything and `modprobe -v module` gives still the same error

Comment: @ElenaGreg What is the output of `uname -r`? . You have this error because the linux-headers isn't installed.

Comment: The output is `4.15.0-64-generic`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117731/discussion-between-gad3r-and-elena-greg).

Answer (score 2):

As written on the page, that you've mentioned, if you are using Linux Mint(on page shortened as Mint), you should use:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Linux Mint is Debian based, which means, that it uses apt package manager instead of yum package manager used by Red-Hat like Linux distributions (such as Fedora, CentOS, ...)